Why must LH2 be gassified before the throat in order to accommodate the high heat fluxes in regenerative cooled nozzles?
In NASA Space Vehicle Design Criteria Liquid Rocket Engine Fluid Cooled Combustion Chambers 2.1.1.2 number of passes (page 10) describes that some coolants must be heated before they become effective. I quote: "Liquid hydrogen, for example, is introduced in the expansion section of the RL-10 and J-2 engines, since it must be gasified  before it can accommodate the high heat fluxes at the throat"
Why must hydrogen be a gas and not a liquid in order to accommodate the high heat fluxes?
To my knowledge gasses are worse conductors of heat than liquids and are less "effective" after heating. Plus nucleate boiling will make heat transfer even worse if you allow it to gasify.

Simply because gas has a higher heat capacity?

I would think it's because you don't want the dramatic expansion of a phase change to happen inside the cooling capillaries. Seems like a burst risk.

@user3528438 ... actually, heat capacity for both liquid and gas H2 is almost identical 14.3 J/g. It is also sometimes expressed as J/mol in which case the number is about double.

My guess: Heat flux across the tube will be in proportion to the tube area. When liquid H2 expands into gas, it will need to occupy a larger volume, so more tube area.
